# Simple way to implement a string interpolation in AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I want to implement a string interpolation in AppleScript, similar to the basic python implementation. For example in python:

```
print('Hello {}'.format('earth')) #> Hello World
```

In AppleScript, how do I implement the `format` handler?

```
to format(theString, {tokens})
    -- TODO
end format

log format("Hello {}", {"Apple"})  -- # Hello Apple
```

Answer (score 2):

The python syntax and the AppleScript/ObjC syntax are not compatible.

If you are talking about only one argument there is a simple solution with help of `NSString`'s `stringWithFormat`

```
use AppleScript version "2.5"
use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions

to format(theString, tokens)
    return (current application's NSString's stringWithFormat_(theString, tokens)) as text
end format

log format("Hello %@", "Apple") -- # Hello Apple
```

For more arguments you have to use an `if - else` clause to *convert* the argument array to the ObjC `va_list`

```
to format(theString, tokens)
    set numberOfArguments to count tokens
    if numberOfArguments = 1 then
        return (current application's NSString's stringWithFormat_(theString, item 1 of tokens)) as text
    else if numberOfArguments = 2 then
        return (current application's NSString's stringWithFormat_(theString, item 1 of tokens, item 2 of tokens)) as text
    else if numberOfArguments = 3 then
        return (current application's NSString's stringWithFormat_(theString, item 1 of tokens, item 2 of tokens, item 3 of tokens)) as text
    else
        error "Invalid number of arguments"
    end if
end format

log format("Hello I'm %@ and I'm %@ years old", {"John", 25}) -- # Hello I'm John and I'm 25 years old
```

Comment: Thank you for your sample code. TBH, I'm not yet ready to try the ObjC, at least not yet, I'll give it try and see if I can build from there. My initial idea was to find and replace occurences of {} in the string, similar to when I implemented a find and replace. Just worried it won't be a trivial implementation.

Comment: I'm getting `error "NSString doesn’t understand the “stringWithFormat_” message."` do I need to install/configure anything to make it work?

Comment: You have to put always the three (at least the first two) `use` lines into your script when dealing with AppleScriptObjC. Parsing `{}` is not trivial in AppleScript.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple implementation using sed

```
to format(theString as text, theTokens as list)
    if class of theTokens is text then set theTokens to {theTokens}
    set builtString to theString
    repeat with nextToken in theTokens 
        set builtString to do shell script "echo '" & builtString & "' | sed 's/{}/" & nextToken & "/'"
    end repeat
    return builtString  
end format
```

I have tested it with only 2 scenarios, I'm sure there are more I haven't covered:

```
format("Hello {}", "baby") -- # Hello baby
"Hello {}, how are you {}", {"baby", "mom"}  -- # Hellow baby, how are you mom
```